# mongod is not working in my hyper terminal [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] build index done. scanned 0 total records. 0 secs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am keep getting this error in my hyper terminal:

2021-09-04T09:42:59.286+0530 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] build index on: config.system.sessions properties: { v: 2, key: { lastUse: 1 }, name: "lsidTTLIndex", ns: "config.system.sessions", expireAfterSeconds: 1800 }
2021-09-04T09:42:59.287+0530 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh]     building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
2021-09-04T09:42:59.290+0530 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs

Comment: That 'I' after the timestamp indicates those messages are informational, not errors.  What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.